# Using WHERE instead of JOIN

Tags: sql

ALL,

Before MS push on all those `{INNER, OUTER} {LEFT, RIGHT} JOIN ON` thing there was a simple and not confusing  `FROM ... WHERE`.

What I'm looking for is a way to write a following:

Consider having 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(foo_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, text1 char(20));
CREATE TABLE bar(bar_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, text2 char(25), FOREIGN KEY foo_id REFERENCES foo(foo_id));
```

What I am looking for is a query that will return me all rows where `foo.foo_id == bar.foo_id and all records from foo that does not have corresponding rows in bar`, that is written with a simple `WHERE` clause.

I am writing a program in C++ and so I think that when parsing the query text it will be easier to parse it then when using all those ugly joins.

```
SELECT text1, text2 FROM foo, bar WHERE ( /* condition goes here */ );
```

I already have a syntax for all other conditions, just this one is needed.

TIA!!

Comment: No. The JOIN is the proper way to do it. Your desired syntax has been inappropriate since the early '90s and should be avoided. Why are you parsing SQL in C++ yourself?

Comment: Virtually no one parses SQL except by using a parser generator. Those parsers can handle the modern `JOIN` syntax just fine. I am guessing that you are trying to find an excuse to avoid learning the syntax. Come on — this syntax has been standard for literally 30 years.

Comment: @BillKarwin, imagine someone wants to play with synax. So he starts with simple equality and then wants to change to my syntax. And then back. And every time, I need to recreate the SQL to present appropriate syntax. So it's not `parsing`per se, but appropriately changing it on the fly. Which is I I think parsing.

Comment: On top of that all those joins are very confusing and completely unreadable. Especially if there is more than 3 tables in query

Comment: The query you are describing involves an outer join.  There have been, and probably still are, DBMS systems that recognize idiosyncratic syntaxes for that, but what do you know?  There is a nice, *standard* syntax for it that is recognized by *all* DBMS systems that support that kind of join at all, involving the keywords "OUTER JOIN".

Comment: _simple and not confusing_ `WHERE` syntax for outer joins is ambigous as it refers to columns. SQL-92 syntax is _not_ ambiguous as it refers to tables. If you want non confusing syntax, you need to use SQL-92

Comment: _very confusing and completely unreadable_ This is opinion not fact. I'm sure it is unreadable if you're only used to old style syntax.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I don't know what is so nice about something like this: `SELECT a,b,c FROM foo INNER JOIN bar OUTER JOIN baz INNER JOIN foo OUTER JOIN my_table INNER JOIN your_table INNER JOIN bar...` ? Can someone in the right mind read all this code? And the more tables you throw in the more spaghetti it will become.  And God forbid you have somewhere 2 fields as PK. On top of that you will type twice as much as you need. Now for someone who don't know anything else - it could be a good code. But my eyes would be hurting by even looking at this...

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, do you have an example of such ambiguity? With Where it is nicely split between where to get the data from and what conditions are this data should be based on.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I understand what I am describing. I also gave you a reason why I want to se a query as such and not to se joins. I don't see any contr-argument about why I should other than `it is standard`. However, since when using `WHERE` is not?

Comment: It is a fact that using the `WHERE` based syntax for outer joins is not standard. Oracle and Sybase each invented their own proprietary syntax for outer joins before the standard was settled. But they are different, and only work in their respective implementations (and Microsoft SQL Server, because it derived from Sybase). Those nonstandard syntax forms were _less_ readable than the ANSI syntax. Your objection to using the standard syntax is absurd.

Comment: I've put an example of ambiguity below. Ambiguity invites unexpected bugs. I suggest you be a defensive programmer and use syntax that isn't ambiguous, and stop using syntax that was depracated many years ago.

Comment: "*Can someone in the right mind read all this code?*"  -- Yes, lots of people can.  In fact, lots of people find it *easier* to read and understand, because it segregates join criteria (on a per-join basis, even) from filter criteria.  If you want obscure then look at the proprietary outer-join syntaxes that Oracle and Sybase invented.  Microsoft is not responsible for the current syntax, but I don't in the least blame them for pushing use of the modern syntax over what they had to offer before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you effectively want a left join between foo and bar which using modern syntax would be:

```
SELECT f.text1, b.text2
FROM foo f LEFT JOIN bar b
ON f.foo_id = b.foo_id
```

Using outdated non-proprietary syntax:

```
SELECT f.text1, b.text2 
FROM foo f, bar b
WHERE f.foo_id = b.foo_id
UNION ALL
SELECT text1, NULL
FROM foo
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bar WHERE foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id)
```

Or deprecated SQL Server:

```
SELECT f.text1, b.text2
FROM foo f, bar b
WHERE f.foo_id *= b.foo_id
```

Comment: so there is no simple WHERE clause for that? I need to union both queries?

Comment: WHERE clause is per-SELECT.  You either have to use a UNION as shown or a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @OldProgrammer ,thank you. got it.

Comment: @Catherine, I will accept your answer. Thank you. However after careful thinking I think I will bite the bullet and will work with the join just for this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but an example of ambiguity

## Old join syntax

Note that in the where clause we have ambiguity. One field defines an outer join, the other defines an inner join. This is a trivial example. In the real world with more complex queries, this ambuguity invites bugs. I was very resistant to SQL-92 But once this bit me (in Oracle) I forced myself to switch to SQL-92. That was probably over ten years ago. There's really no excuse to not be using SQL-92 syntax any more.

```
SELECT f.text1, b.text2
FROM foo f, bar b
WHERE f.foo_id *= b.foo_id
AND   f.z_id = b.z_id
```

## SQL 92 syntax

There can be no ambiguity here as the join type is defined between tables.

```
SELECT f.text1, b.text2
FROM foo f
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar b
ON f.foo_id = b.foo_id
AND   f.z_id = b.z_id
```

A schema that supports the above example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (foo_id INT, z_id INT)
CREATE TABLE bar (foo_id INT, z_id INT)
```

Comment: and what would be the schema for this?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. These are just arbitrary sample tables to illustrate a point. The schema is irrelevant for this purpose.

Comment: can you throw in the schema nevertheless, Just for my curiosity

Comment: I have thrown in the schema.